# ocaml - array of record with mutable field

Tags: ocaml, mutable, records

I'm new to OCaml and i'm trying to understand the concept of `mutable record field`.

I'd like to create an array of records and that record contains a boolean mutable field. So i did something like:

```
type t = {i: int; mutable b: bool};;
```

*I want to be able to change the value of the 'b' field of the record, so i put it `mutable`*

```
let m = Array.make 10 ({i = 5; b = false});;
```

Here i try to set the *b* field of the record located at the first index of my array :

```
(Array.get m 0).b <- true;;
```

The problem is want i do it, it will set 'b' field of all the records of the array, and this is not what i want.

Does the mutable fields of a same record share the same memory emplacement? How can i do to  change the value of the 'b' field of a specific record?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As the documentation states](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Array.html), `Array.make` creates an array whose elements are all physically equal. That's not a problem if these elements are immutable, but as you saw, you have to take that into account if they are mutable.

What you can do is use `Array.init`, to create a different object for every cell of your array:

```
let m = Array.init 10 (fun _ -> {i = 5; b = false});;
```